# Cannot find module 'fcm-node' error when sending IOS Push Notification using Cloud Functions & NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am an IOS Dev trying to setup a simple notification alert when a field in a database changes. I am using the following code to try to send a test message when my "tester" collection gets a new document:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");

const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");


initializeApp();

exports.sendListenerPushNotification = onDocumentCreated("/tester/{documentId}", (event) => {
  const name = event.data.data().name;
  logger.log("Triggered", event.params.documentId, name);
  
  const FCM = require("fcm-node");

  const serverKey = require("PATH_TO_KEY"); // put the generated private key path here

  const fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

  const message = { // this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
    to: "DEVICE_ID",
    collapse_key: "your_collapse_key",

    notification: {
      title: "Title of your push notification",
      body: "Body of your push notification",
    },

  };

  fcm.send(message, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
  });
});
```

When I add the new document the message is never received (real device) and then when i check the log in Firebase, I can see that it tries to fire but gives the error:

Cannot find module 'fcm-node'.

I have used `npm install fcm-node` and added `declare module 'fcm-node';` in my index.d.ts file as I read they could be fixes, but nothing seems to shift this error.

I'm obviosly missing something but could some kind person please tell me what? I am new to this stuff & the docs are either outdated or incredibly confusing!

Thanks in advance.